# mongoose async / await

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, graphql

I am learning on node js and graphql using mongodb and apollo server, the code below works as expected, however I have a feeling that the code can be improved. Here is the snippet on my graphql resolvers:

```
Mutation: {
...,
createJob: async (parent, args, { Customer, Employee, Job }) => {
  const newJob = await new Job(args).save();
  newJob.assigned.map(async(employeeId) => {
    const assignedEmployee = await Employee.findById(employeeId);
    assignedEmployee.jobsHistory.push(newJob._id);
    await assignedEmployee.save()
  });
  const customer = await Customer.findById(newJob.customer);
  customer.jobs.push(newJob._id);
  await customer.save();
  return newJob;
}
```

As I said the code works as expected, but looking at the many awaits, I cant stop but wondering if improvements can be made. Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Why do you think many `await`s would be bad?

Comment: Does whatever calls `createJob` understand that it returns a promise and handle that accordingly? (`map` certainly doesn't, so that's a problem -- as is using `map` without doing anything with the array it returns.)

Comment: Actually you are even missing one: the promises created inside `assigned.map(…)` are never awaited. You'll want to wrap that in `await Promise.all(…)`.

Answer (score 0):

The multiple `await`s are just the nature of `async`/`await`. You have to flag up each and every place you're waiting for an asynchronous operation to occur.

The main problem with that code is that you're ignoring the return value of `map`, and so ignoring the results of the promises created by the `async` function you're passing `map`. **Any** time you call `map` and don't do anything with its return value, you know you're using either the wrong tool (use `forEach` when you don't need the array `map` returns) or doing something else wrong.

Assuming you want the employee updates to run in parallel, and that you want to wait for all of them to complete before updating the customer, you'd want to `await Promise.all(...)` the array `map` returns:

```
createJob: async (parent, args, { Customer, Employee, Job }) => {
  const newJob = await new Job(args).save();
  await Promise.all(newJob.assigned.map(async(employeeId) => {    // ***
    const assignedEmployee = await Employee.findById(employeeId);
    assignedEmployee.jobsHistory.push(newJob._id);
    await assignedEmployee.save();
  }));
  const customer = await Customer.findById(newJob.customer);
  customer.jobs.push(newJob._id);
  await customer.save();
  return newJob;
}
```

But presumably there's no need to wait for the employee updates before finding the customer, so we can improve that slightly by searching for the customer in parallel with the employee updates:

```
createJob: async (parent, args, { Customer, Employee, Job }) => {
  const newJob = await new Job(args).save();
  const customerPromise = Customer.findById(newJob.customer);     // ***
  await Promise.all(newJob.assigned.map(async(employeeId) => {
    const assignedEmployee = await Employee.findById(employeeId);
    assignedEmployee.jobsHistory.push(newJob._id);
    await assignedEmployee.save();
  }));
  const customer = await customerPromise;                         // ***
  customer.jobs.push(newJob._id);
  await customer.save();
  return newJob;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for detailed answer, I guess my itch was due to the missing return on that map operator! Just a quick one, I cant seem to see the different between your first code and the second one. The second code seems to run the same with the first one, except Customer promise is assigned to a const

Comment: @scubadude: The first one starts all the employee work, waits for it to finish, then finds the customer, updates it, and saves it. The second one starts finding the customer and while that's running starts all the employee work, waits for all the employee work to finish, waits for finding the customer to finish, and then updates the customer. As I said in the answer, it runs the operation of finding the customer in parallel with the employee operations instead of serially after them, possibly saving a few milliseconds of elapsed time. :-)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer